# Python print function using mysqlcursor overwriting first character

Tags: python, mysql, command-prompt

I have encountered a strange error when printing from my database, unsure if the problem is due to python decode or otherwise. I tried using sys.stdout.write('.') which has similar output problems

*update 1
Powershell has same output and varying windowsize has no effect https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcsnL.jpg

*update 2
Solution found: adding field.decode().strip() instead of field.decode() removed '/r' character

Thank you @tdelaney

## Code

```
import mysql.connector
import sys
import os
import sys
from datetime import datetime

#################################

# Database settings

hostname = "localhost"
username = "root"
password = "---------"
database = "weatherdb"
port = 3306

# arguments
csvFile = ""
tableName =""

#################################

# Simple routine to run a query on a database and print the results:
def doQuery(conn):
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute( "SELECT * FROM weather_record" )
    count = 0
    for row in cur:
        res = ""
        for field in row:
            res = res + str(field.decode())+ "|"  # line in question
            print(res)               
        res = res + "\n"

#################################
# Get user arguments
def main(argv):
    if(len(sys.argv)== 3):
        # correct number of arguments
        pw = sys.argv[2]
        csvFile = sys.argv[1]
        loadToDB()
    else:
        # incorrect number of arguments
        currentFileName = os.path.basename(__file__)
        print(f"usage {currentFileName} inputfile.csv tableName")
        sys.exit(2)


#################################

print("Using mysql.connector…")
myConnection = mysql.connector.connect(host=hostname, user=username, port=port, passwd=password, db=database)
doQuery(myConnection)
myConnection.close()

#################################

# Run main function on script start
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

## Database table

all fields are **varchar**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
  <head>
    <title>weather_record</title>
    <meta name="GENERATOR" content="HeidiSQL 9.4.0.5125">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
      thead tr {background-color: ActiveCaption; color: CaptionText;}
      th, td {vertical-align: top; font-family: "Tahoma", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; padding: 3px; }
      table, td {border: 1px solid silver;}
      table {border-collapse: collapse;}
      thead .col0 {width: 101px;}
      thead .col1 {width: 82px;}
      thead .col2 {width: 85px;}
      thead .col3 {width: 67px;}
      thead .col4 {width: 85px;}
      thead .col5 {width: 78px;}
      thead .col6 {width: 122px;}
      thead .col7 {width: 142px;}
      thead .col8 {width: 135px;}
      thead .col9 {width: 86px;}
      thead .col10 {width: 102px;}
      thead .col11 {width: 118px;}
      thead .col12 {width: 98px;}
      thead .col13 {width: 118px;}
      thead .col14 {width: 119px;}
      thead .col15 {width: 86px;}
      thead .col16 {width: 102px;}
      thead .col17 {width: 118px;}
      thead .col18 {width: 98px;}
      thead .col19 {width: 118px;}
      thead .col20 {width: 119px;}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <table caption="weather_record (27 rows)">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="col0">date</th>
          <th class="col1">minTemp</th>
          <th class="col2">maxTemp</th>
          <th class="col3">rainfall</th>
          <th class="col4">evaporation</th>
          <th class="col5">sunshine</th>
          <th class="col6">maxWindGustDir</th>
          <th class="col7">maxWindGustSpeed</th>
          <th class="col8">maxWindGustTime</th>
          <th class="col9">9amTemp</th>
          <th class="col10">9amHumidity</th>
          <th class="col11">9amCloudCover</th>
          <th class="col12">9amWindDir</th>
          <th class="col13">9amWindSpeed</th>
          <th class="col14">9amAirPressure</th>
          <th class="col15">3pmTemp</th>
          <th class="col16">3pmHumidity</th>
          <th class="col17">3pmCloudCover</th>
          <th class="col18">3pmWindDir</th>
          <th class="col19">3pmWindSpeed</th>
          <th class="col20">3pmAirPressure</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

<td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col0">2017-02-28</td>
          <td class="col1">10.9</td>
          <td class="col2">33.3</td>
          <td class="col3">0</td>
          <td class="col4"></td>
          <td class="col5"></td>
          <td class="col6">N</td>
          <td class="col7">30</td>
          <td class="col8">09:24</td>
          <td class="col9">21.2</td>
          <td class="col10">66</td>
          <td class="col11"></td>
          <td class="col12">SE</td>
          <td class="col13">7</td>
          <td class="col14">1022.3</td>
          <td class="col15">32.1</td>
          <td class="col16">22</td>
          <td class="col17"></td>
          <td class="col18">NNE</td>
          <td class="col19">9</td>
          <td class="col20">1019.9
</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table
  </body>
</html>
```

## Output

The output was shown on **command line in windows** if that makes a difference

```
C:\Python>python csvToDb.py
Using mysql.connector…
2017-02-28|
2017-02-28|10.9|
2017-02-28|10.9|33.3|
2017-02-28|10.9|33.3|0|
2017-02-28|10.9|33.3|0||
2017-02-28|10.9|33.3|0|||
2017-02-28|10.9|33.3|0|||N|
2017-02-28|10.9|33.3|0|||N|30|
2017-02-28|10.9|33.3|0|||N|30|09:24|
2017-02-28|10.9|33.3|0|||N|30|09:24|21.2|
2017-02-28|10.9|33.3|0|||N|30|09:24|21.2|66|
2017-02-28|10.9|33.3|0|||N|30|09:24|21.2|66||
2017-02-28|10.9|33.3|0|||N|30|09:24|21.2|66||SE|
2017-02-28|10.9|33.3|0|||N|30|09:24|21.2|66||SE|7|
2017-02-28|10.9|33.3|0|||N|30|09:24|21.2|66||SE|7|1022.3|
2017-02-28|10.9|33.3|0|||N|30|09:24|21.2|66||SE|7|1022.3|32.1|
2017-02-28|10.9|33.3|0|||N|30|09:24|21.2|66||SE|7|1022.3|32.1|22|
2017-02-28|10.9|33.3|0|||N|30|09:24|21.2|66||SE|7|1022.3|32.1|22||
2017-02-28|10.9|33.3|0|||N|30|09:24|21.2|66||SE|7|1022.3|32.1|22||NNE|
2017-02-28|10.9|33.3|0|||N|30|09:24|21.2|66||SE|7|1022.3|32.1|22||NNE|9|
|017-02-28|10.9|33.3|0|||N|30|09:24|21.2|66||SE|7|1022.3|32.1|22||NNE|9|1019.9
usage csvToDb.py inputfile.csv tableName
```

as you can see in the second last line, the first character has been overwritten by the '|' character. Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't your command prompt wrapping? Try running the script in PowerShell and make the window bigger.

Comment: Powershell has the same output. http://imgur.com/a/eWnpP

Comment: Maybe there is an odd character like a \r in there. For debug, change it to `repr(field.decode())` - you'll have extra quotes in there but will see odd chars.

Comment: `<td class="col20">1019.9` wraps. So, `field.decode().strip()` may fix it. BTW, I don't think you need that extra `str(...)` there.

Comment: Thank you that fixed the problem, yes it appears that 1019.9 has a \r character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In standard terminals The `\r` character moves the insertion point back to the start of the current line. If the front of your line is being overwritten, there is a good chance its the guilty party.

The root cause IMHO is that the data was not properly scrubbed when being put into the database. If you can't clean up the DB itself, the solution is to scrub every time you use it.